# Is there any benefit to leveling a spirit before dismissing?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I've got duplicates of a few spirits.  Is there any reason to level them up before dismissing them?  What about the spirits that can be enhanced at level 99?  Is there a difference between dismissing an enhanced version over a normal version?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, there is a benefit to leveling a spirit before dismissing them. Higher level spirits yield more SP when dismissed.

#### SP for level 1 primary spirits

1. **Novice**
   100 SP
2. **Advanced**
   200 SP
3. **Ace**
   400 SP
4. **Legendary**
   800 SP

#### SP for level 99 primary spirits

1. **Novice**
     500 SP
2. **Advanced**
   1000 SP
3. **Ace**
   2000 SP
4. **Legendary**
   4000 SP

The above list is valid for all primary spirits, regardless of their Type (Red, Blue, Green), Power, Skill, Support Slots, or whether they can be enhanced or are already enhanced.

Since enhanced spirits normally have a higher star rating than their base version, enhancing them may increase the amount of SP gained when dismissing them, assuming you intend to level up the enhanced version, that is.

Keep in mind that feeding snacks to spirits costs SP. It costs 8 SP per 250 experience points, and the amount of experience needed to level up increases with their level and rating. Using Snacks to increase a spirit's level before dismissing it may therefore diminish your returns, or even incur losses.

---

Not part of the question, but for completeness:

#### SP for support spirits:

1. **Novice**

   1. 100 SP for 1 slot
   2. 100 SP for 2 slots (this is not a mistake)
2. **Advanced**

   1. 200 SP for 1 slot
   2. 250 SP for 2 slots
3. **Ace**

   1. 400 SP for 1 slot
   2. 500 SP for 2 slots
   3. 600 SP for 3 slots
4. **Legendary**

   1. 800 SP for 1 slot
   2. 1000 SP for 2 slots
   3. 1200 SP for 3 slots

<sub>Since I couldn't find any 3-slotted Novice or Advanced support spirits, this list may be incomplete</sub>

Comment: Do enhanced spirits have a different core than the un-enhanced version?

Comment: @Batophobia. I was trying to figure it out by doing a reverse-lookup summon, but couldn't select any enhanceable or enhanced spirit. Either they're not relevant for summoning, or I still don't own one that is. I'll need to do more research before I can say for certain, however.

Comment: @Batophobia. After some more research, I can confirm that enhanced and not enhanced spirits yield different cores. I still don't know whether this affects summoning, though. Interestingly, when you try to dismiss an enhanced spirit, you get the same warning as when you try to dismiss a Legendary spirit. Also interesting: no Legendary cores or spirits are listed in Reverse Lookup. It's possible that summoning does not require enhanced or Legendary spirits.

Comment: I wonder if dojo trainings also matter.  Would one with a style be worth more?  What about one that's trained at all dojos?

Comment: @Batophobia. Good point. I haven't bothered with training, so I neglected testing for that. I'll come back to you when I've trained a few spirits.